# Sqlite update with inner query select

Tags: sqlite

According to all examples my query should be executing. I am trying to update new column on my table with the last 4 digits of the phone number like so :

```
UPDATE users 
SET users.phone_last_4 = t.lastFour
FROM  
(  
    select substr( phone_number, -4) as lastFour from users
) t;
```

Also tried this:

```
UPDATE users 
    SET users.phone_last_4 = t.lastFour
    FROM  
    (  
        select substr( phone_number, -4) as lastFour from users
    ) AS t;
```

Both fail with same error :

```
near ".": syntax error: UPDATE users
SET users.
```

What could I possibly do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not support joins for the [`UPDATE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) statement and also this syntax containing `FROM` .
In your case I can't see why you need it.
Just do:

```
UPDATE users 
SET phone_last_4 = substr(phone_number, -4)
```